# dotnet error : Unable to obtain lock file access on '/tmp/NuGetScratch/lock/

Tags: dotnet-cli

**Passos para reproduzir**

dotnet build or dotnet run

**Comportamento esperado**

Run or Build app

**Comportamento atual**

```
Getting ready...
The template "ASP.NET Core with Angular" was created successfully.

Processing post-creation actions...
Running 'dotnet restore' on /home/limup/Documents/Projetos/Limup/salao/salao.csproj...
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.101/NuGet.targets(123,5): error : Unable to obtain lock file access on '/tmp/NuGetScratch/lock/b19d3901039706ea82571abad7c98ec690508d4b' for operations on '/home/limup/Documents/Projetos/Limup/salao/obj/salao.csproj.nuget.cache'. This may mean that a different user or administator is holding this lock and that this process does not have permission to access it. If no other process is currently performing an operation on this file it may mean that an earlier NuGet process crashed and left an inaccessible lock file, in this case removing the file '/tmp/NuGetScratch/lock/b19d3901039706ea82571abad7c98ec690508d4b' will allow NuGet to continue. [/home/limup/Documents/Projetos/Limup/salao/salao.csproj]

Restore failed.
Post action failed.
Description: Restore NuGet packages required by this project.
Manual instructions: Run 'dotnet restore'
```

**Dados do ambiente**

dotnet --info

```
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
Version: 3.1.101
Commit: b377529961

Runtime Environment:
OS Name: fedora
OS Version: 31
OS Platform: Linux
RID: fedora.31-x64
Base Path: /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.101/

Host (useful for support):
Version: 3.1.1
Commit: a1388f194c

.NET Core SDKs installed:
3.1.101 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.1 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.1 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

**Obs**

Tentei fazer correções no restore dotnet, mas recebi o mesmo erro.

Não tive esse problema com o dotnet sdk 2.0.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em português. Tal como o nome sugere, o idioma oficial usado aqui é o português. Assim sendo, você poderia por favor traduzir sua pergunta? Caso prefira, você também pode fazer essa mesma pergunta no site em inglês do StackOverflow.

Comment: Claro! Feito a tradução.

Comment: Se você ler a mensagem de erro até o final, você vai encontrar: `This may mean that a different user or administator is holding this lock and that this process does not have permission to access it. If no other process is currently performing an operation on this file it may mean that an earlier NuGet process crashed and left an inaccessible lock file, in this case removing the file '/tmp/NuGetScratch/lock/b19d3901039706ea82571abad7c98ec690508d4b' will allow NuGet to continue.`

Comment: nesse caso só precisa remover o arquivo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Senhores, consegue resolver a situação com os seguintes comandos:

```
export TMPDIR=/tmp/NuGetScratch/
```

e

```
mkdir -p ${TMPDIR}
```

Obrigado a todos.